# Multiplayer: Fastest way to rank up

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I have been playing the game for quite a while now. But, I have been noticing that I was ranking very slowly in multiplayer.

In your opinion, what would be the fastest mode to rank up?

What else do you think ranks you up fast. Should I focus on challenges? Should I play super-stealthy? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Personally play **Assassinate**

Sometimes I dont do as well, but to me, its the easiest game mode to get experience.

I dont really focus on challenges at all, the XP doesnt seem worth it IMO.

But thats just me.